# Passing a pointer to a function expecting a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

There is function that I can not edit it which has the following declaration:

```
void foo(std::vector<uchar>& vector_to_filled_with_data);
```

I want to call this function but I want it to fill a pointer instead:

```
void method_that_would_called_from_another_place(){
     uchar* to_be_filled =/*new uchar[n]*/;
     foo(to_be_filled);
}
```

P.S. commented part is optional.. I can erase it or leave it.
I know it is totally bad behavior. However, it is for native-manged wrapper so I have to deal with raw pointers.

EDIT:
I want the data to live out of the scope so getting 'vec.data' is not an option.
I want it to be thread-safe

Comment: did you try this what is error?

Comment: Just use a `vector<>` to  pass, and take it's `data()` later.

Comment: @shami it would not even compile

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I need to keep the data after the vector goes out of the scope

Comment: So you want the data to outlive the `main()` function? Please post a more meaningful example.

Comment: This is precisely why such functions should take iterator pairs, not specific containers. Extremely poorly-designed library you're working with. #smh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a vector, create an array and then copy the data from the vector:

```
std::vector<uchar> to_be_filled;
foo(to_be_filled);
uchar* ptr = new uchar[to_be_filled.size()];
std::copy(to_be_filled.begin(), to_be_filled.end(), ptr);
```

Comment: it seems that there is no option rather than copying the data :(

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Unfortunately no. However, since you're programming in C++ you can *overload* the function with your own that does this copying, and takes a reference to the pointer as an argument. Wrapping and hiding this.

Comment: Why must the data be copied? There is nothing in the question that requires that.

Comment: @juanchopanza the op wants to keep a pointer that outlives the vector. I understand that you perhaps want a static vector, but who knows where this code is running and whether this is an option.

Comment: OP isn't providing enough information to determine whether that is actually necessary.

Comment: @juanchopanza: It can be deduced. OP's third-party function takes a ref-to-vector instead of an iterator pair, but needs the function to perform its duty on an arbitrary buffer through a pointer pair. Since `std::vector` cannot temporarily take ownership of arbitrary buffers, copying will have to take place. The third-party function is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

If the array for some reason is not touchable and the function is not touchable you have to copy the data.

so you construct the vector from the array. and after returning you need to copy the returned data back to the array.

`std::vector` owns the pointer to the internal data. You could exchange the allocator to avoid it from freeing the data afterwards but that changes the type from `std::vector<char>`.

And given the fact that you want to pass a pointer (without its size) the function would be unsafe to mutate your array.

So I would rather try and get rid of the owning array or try to get the function accept other parameters.

code

```
#include <vector>

void foo(std::vector<char> &data) {
    data.push_back("a"); // attention overflow behaviour
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    using namespace std;
    char arr[5] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
    vector<char> cp(&arr[0], &arr[5]);

    foo(cp);

    // somehow handle buffer overflows
    copy(&foo.data[0], &foo.data()[5], arr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the two options are not available for me. the function is untouchable and the array should be an dynamic array due to the need to pass its address to a manged code.

Comment: be aware that you might want to have a pointer to pointer instead. otherwise you cannot reallocate if the data is bigger than your buffer.